# Charger cable vs Lighting to USB Camera Adapter

Tags: ipad, usb, camera, lightning

My iPad came with the normal Lightning -> USB Type A Male charger cable.
I want to connect it to my Roland piano and the piano's manual mentions the need for a camera connection kit - so apparently I need this: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD821ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter

Now these cables (charger and the above adapter) look very similar to me (both have USB Type A at one end, although one is male and the other is female).

Do they have different wiring/chips?

Answer (score 1):

I use an apple camera connection kit adaptor to connect my iPad to both my RolandRD800 & Kurzweil Forte keyboards. My iPad runs the Unrealbook app which contains all my set lists & songs, and behind each song PDF is a midi HEX string which is sent to both keyboards automatically when I select a song, and this midi HEX string selects the correct patches on each keyboard I require to play the song.

Here is exactly how I set up my connections:

- My iPad has the iPad camera connection adaptor plugged directly into it
- Plugged into the other end of the iPad camera connection adaptor is a mini-USB 4 port HUB
- Into the mini-USB hub I blug two standard printer cables (usb type 'a' to usb type 'b')
- Then I plug the other ends 'usb type b' into the keyboards computer ports (one into the Roland and one into the Kurzweil)

There you go. All good. Works a treat. You should now be connected.

NOTE: Your iPad will not charge from your Roland. There is no voltage at the Roland computer port connection to provide a charge. Also the iPad camera connection adaptor is not configured to provide charge to your iPad. It is made purely to connect to a camera and transfer photos.

Answer (score 0):

Apple made the camera adapter for photo-transfer purposes. It brings nothing else.

There is no difference in terms of charging if you use the -normal- lightning to USB adapter.

So yeah, go with the charger cable.

Comment: "no difference in terms of charging" - I'm interested if there are differences in terms of data transfer. For what it's worth, I can't connect the iPad to the piano using the charger cable, but users on online forums claim they were able to connect these devices using the cable linked in my question. So there may be differences between those cables?

Comment: What is the purpose of connecting your iPad to the piano ?

Comment: For this app: http://www.roland.com/products/piano_partner/ (the piano is in the 'Compatible' list).